# Change `numberOfItemsInSection` parameter of a collection view

Tags: swift, xcode, collections, uicollectionview

How is it possible to change `numberOfItemsInSection` parameter of a collection view?

I have made a basic setup of a collection view. And now I try to make a button, that changes the amount of items in it.

The general setup is a standard one:

```
   func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        arrayA.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell            
        cell.imageView.image = arrayA[indexPath.item][0].image
        return cell
    }
```

The question is - how to configure a button, so it could change `numberOfItemsInSection` parameter from current `arrayA.count` to some other (e.x. `arrayB.count`)?

Example: [image]

Comment: If `arrayA` and `arrayB` are of the same type there is a better way: Declare a common array as data source and on button press copy the contents of `arrayA` or `arrayB` to the common array. In `numberOfItemsInSection` return `commonArray.count`. And if there is only one section you can delete `numberOfSections`.

Comment: pass an `array` instead of `1`. And change the size of array on click of your Button.

Comment: @vadian - can you please give a tip, what to do if their types are different?

Comment: Then you have to add `if - else` or `switch` statements to display the heterogenous types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a common a flag to toggle between arrayA and arrayB. When the button is clicked as

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return isUseArrayA ? arrayA.count : arrayB.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell           
    cell.imageView.image = isUseArrayA ? arrayA[indexPath.item][0].image : arrayB[indexPath.item][0].image
    return cell
}

@IBAction func changeSource(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == 0 {
       isUseArrayA = true
       sender.tag = 1
    } else {
       sender.tag = 0
       isUseArrayA = false
    } 
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// No need of numberOfSection because it is bydefault 1.

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    arrayA.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.imageView.image = arrayA[indexPath.item][0].image
    return cell
}

@IBAction func changeArrayCount(sender: UIButton) {
    arrayA.append(image)
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Kumar, thanks! But changing arrayA will lead to some undesirable changes in other aspects of an app. Is it possible to modify the code so it wont change the arrays? Ideal way will be to use method variable Int.

Comment: Actually, Your question description is not enough to understand what exactly you want to achieve. If you can share the screen or gif of your app for better understanding. so that I can help you more.

Comment: I have added a gif to the question. Images on the left present the desired behaviour of a collection view.